# Get real architecture of M1 Mac regardless of Rosetta

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, shell, rosetta

I need to retrieve the real architecture of a Mac regardless of if the process is running through Rosetta or not.

Right now in Node.js, `process.arch` returns `x64` and in shell, `uname -m` returns `x86_64`.

Comment: My use case here is to ship the arm version of the app through auto update. Also track who are running emulated software and link that with performance or other issues.

Comment: It should be possible to detect existence of Rosetta 2 and assume arm.

Comment: There's [this note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/about_the_rosetta_translation_environment#3616845) on how to do that in general. I have doubts that there is a Nodejs module already written for this, though.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to do the same in a shell script? (if your Terminal app is running in x86, uname -m will not return arm)

Comment: Write an executable that does the actual check. In the script, try to execute the binary and check its results and whether or not it fails to actually execute.

Comment: This is great for trying to get cross-architecture Vagrant images working: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12610

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to @Ouroborus, [this note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/about_the_rosetta_translation_environment#3616845) describes how to figure out if your app is translated.

If it's translated:

```sh
$ sysctl sysctl.proc_translated
sysctl.proc_translated: 1
```

If not:

```sh
$ sysctl sysctl.proc_translated
sysctl.proc_translated: 0
```

On non-ARM Macs:

```sh
$ sysctl sysctl.proc_translated
sysctl: unknown oid 'sysctl.proc_translated'
```

Comment: For ease of scripting, you can also use `sysctl -n sysctl.proc_translated`. `-n` will cause `sysctl` to only print the value.

Comment: If you want to ignore unknown oid values, you can run `sysctl -in sysctl.proc_translated`. This will only print the value without the error message.

Answer (score 2):

As @Elmo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65347893/1161484) indicates, the command line `sysctl -n sysctl.proc_translated` or the native equivalent `sysctlbyname()` call will indicate whether you are running under Rosetta.

Two other `sysctl` values are relevant.  On M1 hardware without Rosetta, these values are returned:

```sh
hw.cputype: 16777228
hw.cpufamily: 458787763
```

`hw.cputype` is `0x0100000C` (CPU_TYPE_ARM64) and `hw.cpufamily` is `0x1b588bb3` (CPUFAMILY_ARM_FIRESTORM_ICESTORM).

However, when executed under Rosetta, the low-level machine code which collects CPUID takes precendence and following two values are returned, both via `sysctlbyname()` and the command line:

```sh
hw.cputype: 7
hw.cpufamily: 1463508716
```

These correspond to `0x7` (CPU_TYPE_X86) and `0x573b5eec` (INTEL_WESTMERE).

It appears Rosetta reports an x86-compatible Westmere chip under Rosetta, but this choice seems consistent everywhere I've seen. This "virtual architecture" may be useful information for some programs.

Another possibility presents itself in the IO Registry.  While the default `IOService` plane collects data in real-time, the `IODeviceTree` plane is stored at boot, and includes these entries in the tree (command line `ioreg -p IODeviceTree` or `ioreg -c IOPlatformDevice`):

```sh
cpu0@0  <class IOPlatformDevice, id 0x10000010f, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (180 ms), retain 8>
    | | | {
...
    | | |   "compatible" = <"apple,icestorm","ARM,v8">
```

(for CPUs 0-3)
and

```sh
cpu4@100  <class IOPlatformDevice, id 0x100000113, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (186 ms), retain 8>
    | | | {
...
    | | |   "compatible" = <"apple,firestorm","ARM,v8">
```

(for CPUs 4-7)

This clearly indicates the ARMv8 Firestorm + Icestorm M1 chip.

The same approach should work for the M1 Pro and M1 Max.

Comment: How do I get the GPU core count?

Comment: @tcapelle You should ask that as a new question.