# Is there any way to check if we are using mac M1 in package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, yarn-v2

I want to conditionally run scripts from `package.json` based on whether the user uses M1 MacBook or an Intel Mac (so based on the CPU architecture).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this in the script itself? One script, perhaps that initiates one of two *other* scripts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346260/get-real-architecture-of-m1-mac-regardless-of-rosetta should point you in the right direction for detection.

Comment: yes, my package is dependent on another library that runs the script for intel macs. now I want to have both m1s and normal and don't change the dependency on them.

Comment: thanks @gog, I can use process.arch in package.json now.

Comment: @Konrad no, I want to use if/else statement in one of my scripts in package.json

Comment: You can use if/else in bash and you can run any bash script inside package.json, so what's wrong?